# How to retrieve asp.net media / resources based on logged in user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, static-files, asp.net-core-staticfile

I have an asp.net web api project using token based authentication. my app uploaded and retrieve images and I keep file path in table_myfiles along with the uploaded user ID.

I would like the user to access only the files he have uploaded, which I can identify from the table.

How to protect my resources to restrict access to only to the user based on table_myfile ? And not to anyone without logging in or direct link / path ?

I have been searching for any possible solution for a week now , I think I should implement a middleware to manage access. But I couldn’t find any resources on how to implement the same.

Currently my api shows all resources just by directly accessing the file path/link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple apporach is to remove the vitural folder, or that folders from the web site folders. That way, no simple URL exists for any of the files.

So, for a user to get/see/use/download a file? You present say a listview or some kind of grid (or repeater) that displays and lists out the files.

Then, when they want to download or view a file?

You use response.write and stream the file down to the client side.

Remember, on the server, code behind uses 100% clean and correct windows file paths. For any web based URL, then that folder must be in a valid path of the web site. When they type in a valid URL, it eventually gets translated to that given folder in the site (or a external folder provided when you create a mapped "virtual" folder in IIS. However, if you don't provide that virtual folder, or the folder is NOT in the web site file/folder sets, then no valid URL's exist. However, that folder can be directly used and hit with code behind - any valid server path/folder name is allowed in code behind.

Because when streaming the file, you need path name, file name, AND ALSO the "mine" type. Thankfully, .net 4.5 or later has this ability.

so, from a database (table) I display the file names like this:

[image]

But, if you click on the preview image, that is a image button.

The code behind simply gets/grabs the file name from the database.

I then download (stream) the file to the browser side like this:

```
if (File.Exists(strInternalFullPath))
{
    string strConType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strInternalFullPath);

    binFile = File.ReadAllBytes(strInternalFullPath);
    Response.ContentType = strConType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(strWebUrl));
    Response.BinaryWrite(binFile);
    Response.End();
}
else
    MyToast2(this, btnLink.ClientID.ToString, "File Not found", "We no longer have this file avaiable.");
```

so, this buttion behaves 100% like a link, but there are no existing URL's or path name that points to the files folder from a web based URL.

Remember:

Web based URLs - they auto map from the web site URL to a existing folder.

You can use server.MapPath("some url to file") to "translate" this to a internal file name.

Code based files:

In your .net code (code behind) ANY file name is a standard plane, jane file name that points to a file on the server.

so, once we have that file name from the database, you can steam the file as if the user clicked on a link. But you never have to expose the actual file name, or file path. And no such valid URL's exist on the web site, since you do NOT have that files folder in the web site folder hierarchy - but placed that folder outside of the web site.

As long as that folder is outside of the web folders, and as long as you don't setup a virtual folder that points to that folder outside the web folders?

Then code behind can STILL get/grab/see/use any file on the server. that code uses a full valid windows file name,  - but the web site will have no mapping to such a folder - hence no valid URL's will exist or can be typed in.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effort to help me on this matter, in my case I have an API like http://localhost/api/myfiles which returns fields ('id','title','filepath.jpg'). as per the suggested code I can make individual call to retrieve each image while I click on title like :- http://localhost/api/myfiles/{id} .  can you share my a code which I can use inside this API Controller ? to return a single file only if the user is authenticated. I Use this code to get user ID (    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); )

Comment: Just place the web page that displays the file list in a sub folder in the web site that is secured. Thus the web page that displays the file list in that grid can ONLY be hit by users that are logged on. And that list of files you display in the grid will be based on their logged on ID (GetUserID). So each user will ONLY get a list of THEIR files based on their logon ID. Since no valid URL to download file exists, then each users can only download and see and get their own files based on what is displayed in the grid. So that table of files in database of course stores logon ID in that table.

Comment: As for using web method (API), the above concepts are still the same. The idea is to remove the folder with the files from the web site folders. No URL to a file will exist. The ONLY way to get at a file is to use code behind. We don't care if this is a web page and display of the files, or you create some web method (API) that returns a file based on some file name or whatever you want to pass to that web method. I would strong suggest that you build a web page that displays their file list into a grid view based on their logon + GetUserID. Once working then add API (web method) to that page

Comment: So in that table that stores the list of files, you need to have  column that saves the GetUserID. Thus the grid will ONLY display row from that files table in the database for a given user. And as noted, since no vaild URL's exist, then the only way to see a file list is to be logged on (else you can't get to that web page - it is secured by logon). And once you have that page working then you can add a web method (API - rest call) to that page.  So I would get this web page working, and then you can start a new question - how to make API call based on logon. But get web page working first.

Comment: You have helped me very much on this topic. now my API code looks like this    below

Comment: string fileName = "sample.pdf";
string localFilePath = System.Web.HttpRuntime.BinDirectory + "sample.pdf";

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

return response;

Comment: now i have a file named sample.pdf in bin directory. is it possible for a user to directly access those files ? if not i will check for user authentication and im done on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233028/discussion-between-sulfy-and-albert-d-kallal).

Comment: this is the filepath on server side file:///C://inetpub//wwwroot//wogappApi//bin//sample.pdf, is it possible for a client to access this file directly with any url ?

Comment: and I am able to download the file with http://192.168.1.100:5041/api/values/getfile, kindly let me know if the files in bin or any virtual directory are protected by default and secure

Comment: On local just about any url is valid. Don't use say "bin" folder or some such (bad idea!!!). Just have folder on server (your computer right now) with the files. You could even make sub folders based on ID. Your not running full IIS (internet services). Create a new folder on that site - add the web page to display files in a grid based on user id. Now secure the web page based on the role the user belongs to. You NOT be able to hit or type in that URL unless the user is logged on.  Break this down into separate questions - do you have the page secured? ask a new question how to do then.

Comment: The folder for the fiiles simply does not and should not be inside the folder for the web site - it is that simple. As I stated add a new folder to the site and niside that new folder you place the web page that displays the files as a grid. Now secure that web folder based on Roles the user belongs to. this is standard fair, standard knowledge, and without you having secured that web page, then all other questions are 100% waste of time. that display files web page will be in that sub folder of your web site, but the folder with files is NOT to be in the web site folders.

Comment: While I stated to NOT use bin folder - do consider using adding the asp.net folder called "app_data". Place your files folder inside of that folder. Now - even without logons or anything - no one can type in a URL to those files. Remember, using VS to add this app data folder - don't create the folder yourself.

Comment: So while I have been suggesting to place that files folder outside of the web site - use the app_data folder - you can't type in URL's to that folder - this will be easier for you, since that folder can reside inside of the web site set of folders.